# Change line color in Anychart radar chart

Tags: javascript, radar-chart, anychart

Is it possible to add color to the lines in the following radar chart?
[image]

```
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  // chart type
  var chart = anychart.radar();

  // chart title
  chart.title().text('Spending');

  // series type and data set
  chart.line([
    {x: "Administration", value:"22"},
    {x: "Sales", value:"34"},
    {x: "Marketing", value:"16"},
    {x: "Research", value:"12"},
    {x: "Support", value:"38"},
    {x: "Development", value:"47"}
  ]);

  // draw chart
  chart.container('container').draw();
});
```

I have tried adding `fill`, but it doesn't seem to be working

```
chart.line([
  {x: "Administration", value:"22", fill: "#color-code"},
  {x: "Sales", value:"34", fill: "#color-code"},
  {x: "Marketing", value:"16", fill: "#color-code"},
  {x: "Research", value:"12", fill: "#color-code"},
  {x: "Support", value:"38", fill: "#color-code"},
  {x: "Development", value:"47", fill: "#color-code"}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a line series on a radar plot as [Radar Plot: Line](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Radar_Plot/Line_Chart) says.
So it follows [Line Chart](https://docs.anychart.com/Basic_Charts/Line_Chart) series settings: and you need to set [Stroke](https://docs.anychart.com/Graphics/Stroke_Settings), not fill, for example:

```
  line = chart.line([
    {x: "Administration", value:"22"},
    {x: "Sales", value:"34"},
    {x: "Marketing", value:"16"},
    {x: "Research", value:"12"},
    {x: "Support", value:"38"},
    {x: "Development", value:"47"}
  ]);

  line.stroke('red 3', 2, 2);
```

As it is shown in this [Radar Line Chart with Stroke Settings Sample](https://playground.anychart.com/e6ps2shN):

```
  chart.palette(["Black", "Green"]);
```

Alternatively, you can use [AnyChart Palette](https://docs.anychart.com/Appearance_Settings/Palettes) if you need several different lines: [AnyChart Palette Multiple Lines Radar Chart](https://playground.anychart.com/e6ps2shN/1)

And here is a snippet of the basic sample as well:

```js
anychart.onDocumentReady(function() {

  // chart type
  var chart = anychart.radar();

  // chart title
  chart.title().text('Spending');
  
  // set palette
  chart.palette(["Black", "Green"]);

  // series type and data set
  chart.line([
    {x: "Administration", value:"22"},
    {x: "Sales", value:"34"},
    {x: "Marketing", value:"16"},
    {x: "Research", value:"12"},
    {x: "Support", value:"38"},
    {x: "Development", value:"47"}
  ]);
  
  // series type and data set
  chart.line([
    {x: "Administration", value:"32"},
    {x: "Sales", value:"44"},
    {x: "Marketing", value:"46"},
    {x: "Research", value:"42"},
    {x: "Support", value:"48"},
    {x: "Development", value:"57"}
  ]);
  

  // draw chart
  chart.container('container').draw();
});
```

```css
html, body, #container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.anychart.com/releases/8.2.1/js/anychart-bundle.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```